# if loop can't break

Tags: c#, dao

I am working with dao, My user is adding a table and its field. My programs checks if the table exists, if yes, it is adding only the field, if the table doesn't exist it is adding the table and then appends the field.

My problem is happening when I am trying to add the second field. It is telling me that the table already exists. It is not going through the loop the proper way. can you help?

```
    string tablename = txtNameTable.Text.Trim();
        string fieldname = txtFieldName.Text.Trim();
        string size = txtSize.Text.Trim();

        //create a table
        myTable = clsDataSource.mydb.CreateTableDef(tablename);

        //create fields 
        if (cboFieldType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Text")
        {
            myField = myTable.CreateField(fieldname, DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbText, size);
        }


        if (cboFieldType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "AutoNumber")
        {
            myField = myTable.CreateField(fieldname, DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbLong);
            myField.Attributes = (int)DAO.FieldAttributeEnum.dbAutoIncrField;
        }


        if (cboFieldType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Number")
        {
            myField = myTable.CreateField(fieldname, DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbLong, size);
        }


        if (cboFieldType.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Date")
        {
            myField = myTable.CreateField(fieldname, DAO.DataTypeEnum.dbDate);
        }           


        //check if table exists
        bool tableExist = false;

        foreach (TableDef tb in clsDataSource.mydb.TableDefs)
        {
            if (tb.Name == myTable.Name)
            {
                myTable.Fields.Append(myField);
                tableExist = true;
                break;
            }
        }
            if (tableExist == false)
            {
                myTable.Fields.Append(myField);
                clsDataSource.mydb.TableDefs.Append(myTable);
            }



            //add primary key

            if (ckPK.Checked == true)
            {
                Index myIndex = myTable.CreateIndex("PrimaryKey");
                myField = myIndex.CreateField(fieldname);
                ((IndexFields)myIndex.Fields).Append(myField);
                myIndex.Primary = true;

                try
                {
                    clsDataSource.mydb.TableDefs[myTable.Name].Indexes.Append(myIndex);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("This table already has a primary key", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            Activate(true, true, true);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you merge 2 if statements into one and get rid of unnecessary conditions and brackets?

Comment: What do you mean by unnecessary conditions and brackets?

Comment: `if(tb.Attributes == 0 && tb.Name == myTable.Name) {//your condition}`

Comment: I edited it following your advice. Now i need to find a way to break the loop because he is still telling me that my field already exists but it doesnt.

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand where that myField came from. Are you sure it has any value?

Comment: Why do you have `tb.Attributes == 0` on the if. I don't know DAO but this looks like a collection. Won't it always be different than 0?

Comment: You have to put attributes ==0 to eliminate system table

Comment: "is still telling me that my field already exists but it doesnt" - well, look at where that error message came from.  You print that for any possible exception thrown from  `clsDataSource.mydb.TableDefs[myTable.Name].Fields.Append(myField);`.  There are likely many cases that could cause that to throw.  For one, how is myField initialized?  If none of the if statements is hit and this is null, maybe you're getting a NullReferenceException, etc.  You need to dig into the actual exception being thrown which almost certainly has far more detail than your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is the thing. If you have multiple tables in your foreach statement, then your if statement with checking if Findtable is false being reached only after all tables are iterated. Hence, you have to move your if statement inside the loop, so that it could add a new table in case if it does not exist. Practically, this is how it should look like:

```
    List<String> existingTables = new List<String>();
    foreach (TableDef tb in clsDataSource.mydb.TableDefs)
        {
               if (tb.Attributes == 0 && tb.Name == myTable.Name)
                {
                    clsDataSource.mydb.TableDefs[myTable.Name].Fields.Append(myField);
                    myTable.Fields.Append(myField);
                    clsDataSource.mydb.TableDefs.Append(myTable);
                }         
                else {       
                    existingTables.Add(MyTable.Name.ToString());
                }      
        }//end foreach
    foreach (var el in existingTables){
           MessageBox.Show("This table already exists: {0}", el)
    }//end foreach
```

Thus, you get rid of another condition and add your table right away if it matches all parameters. Moreover, you also get rid of that boolean, which is unnecessary in this case. Once all tables have been iterated, you will exit the loop.

Comment: I am not sure i understand sorry.

Comment: in my loop i check my attribute then if my new table = a table in the database.

Comment: Ok sorry. I just got it but it is not working It is not creating my first table.

Comment: If it is not creating your first table, then the problem is actually with `clsDataSource.mydb.TableDefs.Append(myTable);` I am not sure how in DAO, but it should be something like `mydb.SaveChanges();` that will record your changes to the database once you applied some modifications to it.

Comment: It was creating the tables before. You don't need to save the changes once you append it

Comment: If Append is working, there might be another problem with your `try catch` statement. Whenever it goes to catch part, it breaks the loop and shows you that there is already a record with that value in the database. As a result, you are not adding other tables to the database. Try to remove your `try catch` and leave only if statement. See edited version.

Comment: if i do that, it goes directly to the message box error

Comment: So I am trying to do two if statement. one if tb.name == mytable.name and if tb.name != mytable.name 
Now the problem is that when i m creating my first field in my first table, it is not seeing "myfield" anymore. but it was before :(

Comment: but still not creating it